# "location ~ \.php$" or "upstrem php"?

Tags: php, nginx

I installed Wordpress with Nginx and php-fpm.

I wrote in config file like `location ~ \.php$ {}` and it works.
But some web site explains with `upstrem php {}`.

What is the difference of these two expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

upstream usually is used when you have multiple application servers and nginx works as a proxy to load balance between those servers, you can give each a weight and you can take some servers offline for maintaining and stuff like that.

In this special case you use the upstream with only 1 application server which is actually also running on the local server.

The location method runs on matching locations that end with the extention `.php` and passing it to the php engine, I think both methods would work fine, but i guess the upstream method is better when you plan to scale your server or add more application servers, you can also add multiple upstreams, `upstream php {}` means that you defined an upstream with the name 'php'.

You pass things to the upstream almost like the same concept of named locations, but instead you `proxy_pass` to that block, in this case:

```
proxy_pass http://php;
```

Where `php` is the name of the upstream

Here's a [link to the doc page of the upstream module](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUpstreamModule), if you want to read more about it, I know it says "obsolete" but it's easier to read for a start, then you can find the link to the original doc page at the bottom, [here's a link to it](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html)